# Why does our Backend Programmer handle SSL in this fashion, with a redirect?

Tags: iis, ssl, redirect

Here's the page in question: [www.mchenry.edu/parentorientation](http://www.mchenry.edu/parentorientation). My question is: why does our Backend DB person handle the SSL this way, as a redirect? Isn't there a cleaner way to do it? BTW, we're running IIS. My suspicion is that she doesn't understand what needs to happen in order to make it cleaner, and she refuses to discuss different ways of doing it. I'm a front-end guy so if someone could explain to me why she's doing it this way and if there's a better alternative, I'd be much obliged. BTW, our SSL is at the root, so I'm guessing that any directories beyond this can utilize SSL? Is that correct?

Thanks for any input you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normally handled as a redirect, when a user enters an HTTP address the server will redirect to an HTTPS location.

The other thing is that redirect is usually done to the same location. The way you have it right now is not good and there is no obvious reason for it to be done this way.

Ask her firmly to explain what is the reason behind this decision. You may want to hint her that doing things your own way without sharing them with other developers is not an option when working in a team.

Comment: Thanks for this. Thing is, she has poor communication skills and prefers to do things her own way. I'm just trying to get a better understanding of why she does things the way she does. I'll suggest doing a server redirect, instead of a dirty redirect. Thanks!

Comment: Poor communication skills have nothing to do with blunt refusal to behave team-aware. The first is understandable and can be worked around in one way or another. The last one is just unacceptable.

Comment: Tried to get her to do it, but she said she tried the server redirect once (as opposed to the meta redirect) and it just looped (kept refreshing) so she's opposed to the server redirect now. She probably had it configured wrong or something. Sigh.